# A service installation section in this inf is invalid

Tags: windows-xp, drivers, mtp

When I connect a Samsung phone to my Windows XP SP3, it gives the error

**A service installation section in this inf is invalid**

[image]

I browsed lot of blogs, every post says to try the *Microsoft_User-Mode_Driver_Framework_Install-v1.0-WinXP.exe*. But when install this, I get another error

**Wudf01000 Setup Error**

**Access is denied.**

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot:

Open up your `c:\Windows\System32\` folder

Is there a **file** named `LogFiles`?  If so, delete it

Is there a **folder** called `LogFiles`?  If not, create it

Then try installing `Microsoft_User-Mode_Driver_Framework_Install-v1.0-WinXP.exe`

Comment: There is one folder called `Logfiles`, but I could not delete it. The process `inetinfo.exe`(IIS, I think) locks some files of the folder.

Answer (score 0):

Read this link to enable wudfgroup registry.. and then just update the driver of the MTP from Device manager. It worked for me.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/873148